# Strange messages at boot and no plymouth

Tags: boot, plymouth

After reinstalling ubuntu a couple of days ago (dont ask), ive been getting strange messages at boot up, and i dont seem to have the plymouth boot splash screen thing (whatever the one with the ubuntu logo and the white and orange dots is).

My computer seems to function ok, and boots up fine, it just boots straight to the gdm.

The message im getting is:

`modprobe: FATAL: Could not load lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/modules.dep no such file or directory`

this is displayed twice at boot. Anyone know whats gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a race condition, and it isn't fatal to the boot despite the ominous module-init-tools output.  Please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/642421.

Comment: What is the final accepted solution?